# Module vs normal javascript for function within html

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascript functions defined in a normal `<script>` tag and one imported within a `<script type="module">` tag:

```
<script type="module">
    import { mean } from "./node00.js";
    console.log(mean(1,2,3)); // OK -- just to confirm this works fine
</script>

<script>
    function xNew(x) { console.log("Calling xNew"); }
</script>

<span onclick="mean(1,2,3,4)">Hello</span>
<span onclick="xNew(5)">It's me.</span>
```

It seems that the `mean` function within the module is not accessible to the html, whereas the `xNew` function within the normal script tags is. What is the scoping and accessibility of these two items? And if `module` makes the javascript hidden from the html what would be the point of using it?

Comment: You need to export and import it first

Comment: @mugiseyebrows ok how would that be done then within the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the nature of [`module`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), modules can talk to modules by `import` and `export` only (No communications outside of modules), but you can add events on DOM objects via `document` or `window` which is shared for all modules.

```html
<script type="module">
function sum(a,b) {
    console.log('Calling sum');
    return a+b;
}
document.getElementById("test-sum").onclick = () => sum(2,3)
</script>

<script>
function xNew(x) {
    console.log("Calling xNew");}
</script>

<span id="test-sum">Hello</span>
<span onclick="xNew(2)">It's 'a me, mario</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a script tag having `type="module"` attribute specifies that it to be considered as a Javascript module. It may be importing other Javascript module(s) inside it and becomes a "top-level" module for the imported modules.

For example:

```
// file "module.js"
export var someVar = "Some data";

export function someFunc() {
    return " for output";
}

// this has no "export" prefixed hence cannot be used outside this module 
function someOtherFunction() {
    return 1;
}

<script type="module">
    import {someVar, someFunc} from './module.js';

    // "Some data for output"
    console.log(someVar + someFunc());
</script>
```

In the example above the module that is created is imported using the import statement.

Comment: @ok -- but where is the html? See updated question.

Comment: @David542 did you export the function? i have updated the answer.

Comment: @David542 once you've imported the features into your script, you can use them just like they were defined inside the same file.

Comment: I mean, where is the `span` in your code?